# Makefile for automatic placement of object and dependency file in separate folder

Tags: c++, object, makefile, dependencies, directory

I would like to place the object files of the compiler in a different folder than the source files. I made it working, when using the same folder structure as the way my source code is build up, but this is not the solution i am looking for.

What I would prefer is the following:

Sources:

```
src/main.cpp
src/myClass/myClass.cpp
```

Object:

```
obj/main.o
obj/myClass.o
```

Dependencies

```
dep/main.d
dep/main.d
```

What I have until now is the following

VARIABLES

```
$(OBJLIST)=obj/main.o obj/myClass.o
$(SRCDIR)=src
$(OBJDIR)=obj
```

LINKER

```
$(PROJECT): $(OBJLIST)
    $(CXX) $(OBJLIST) $(LIBS) -o $@
```

COMPILER and here is my *problem*

This is what is working

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(DEPDIR) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM -MT 1_obj/main.o 0_src/main.cpp -o 2_dep/main.dep
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/myClass/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(DEPDIR) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM -MT 1_obj/myClass.o 0_src/myClass/myClass.cpp -o 2_dep/myClass.dep
```

I also have an object called SRCDIRS containing:

```
SRCDIRS
    ./
    ./myClass
```

So i hoped I could merge the compile-definitions to something like

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/$(SRCDIRS)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(DEPDIR) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ @< -o $(DEPDIR)/$(notdir $(basename $<).dep)
```

I hoped this would generalize for both possibilities, but somehow, it seams
it does not loop through SRCDIRS and check for any match.

Comment: The common way is to include the `.d` files in the makefile.

Comment: This is not realy my problem, i would like to know how I can automatically put the o-files in a different folder. But without rebuilding the whole folder structure of the .cpp-files. So, get all the source files from all the folders and subfolders and during compilation put the o-files in a single folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [vpath](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Search.html).  Be aware that VPATH can *only* be used to find source files.

So, something like this:

```
VPATH = $(SRCDIRS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
        ...
```

is all you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. This entirely solved the problem.